# Fully setting up .NET Core Web API to Use Azure AD Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 3.0 Web API project. In which one custom folder **Angular** which is actually a compiled Angular 9 application (When I build my Angular application, output path is set to this folder).

Initially it was Windows Authentication, then been asked to Azure AD which was not familiar for me. But I was able to setup in my Web API just using a startup code

```
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Its working fine such a way that when ever a controller with Autherize directive is there, it asks for Azure AD login and autheticates and backto my application.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class KipController : ControllerBase
{
.....
......
```

Then onward obviously it wont asks for Authentication .
But if we request initially a controller without Authorise it wont ask for login. That's the first problem.

Also if I specify my angular application from there as well, its not asking for credentials or authentication.

So how can I secure the whole application with Azure AD authentication. I mean only authorised user can have access over the whole application. How can I achieve that?

So whats my goal is, when a request to index.html hits, it musts asks the user to login or redirect to azure ad authentication. If an active session already there no need to trigger login..

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't mention about which flow you are using to validate between SPA - Your API - Azure AD so I assume you use `Implicit grant flow` [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). Now let me resolve your puzzle one by one:

1. Then onward obviously it wont asks for Authentication . But if we request initially a controller without Authorise it wont ask for login -> You choose to use `Implicit grant flow` means when your user login successfully on Azure AD page, then your SPA will receive a JWT token [v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#v20). Next, for each calling API, SPA must attach this JWT to HTTP Header `Authorization Bearer={JWT}` to let your API to validate JWT itself. HOWEVER, .NET doesn't come with default Global Authentication so that mean if your Controller doesn't have any `[Authorize]`, mean it allows all. If you are using .NET Core 3.0+, you can add this line in `Startup.cs` for forcing all Controllers must be authorized. Only `[AllowAnonymous]` can bypass.

```cs
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        // Require Authorization for all your Razor Pages
        endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
        
        // Require Authorization for all Controllers (both API or MVC)
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
    });
```

2. how can I secure the whole application with Azure AD authentication. I mean only authorised user can have access over the whole application -> Angular provides to you `CanActivate` which help to prevent any failure case. So you just want to create your own logic to validate which user has `JWT` token or not.
   There are sample code with `SecurityService`. In this class, you need to store `JWT` token.

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{
    constructor(
        private security: SecurityService,
        private router: Router){}

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
      ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
        // If current user have any valid JWT, allow user to continue Route
        if(this.security.isUserSignedIn()){
            return true
        }
        else{
            // If current user doesn't sign in, force user to be Login page
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
        }
      }
}
```

Then you should wrap all your `protected` components in one route below

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {path: 'portal', canActivate:[AuthGuard], children: [
      { path : '', component: DefaultComponent},
      { path : 'first', component : FirstComponent},
      { path : 'two', component: SecondComponent}
    ]}
];
```

Then add `routes` to your `RoutingModule`

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```